# My for-loop will not store all my info in a list

Tags: c#, list, pdf, for-loop, file-io

I am trying read a 200 page pdf file. The data  is in excel like format and I would like to add each line into a list.

The for-loop that I currently have will only store the lines from the current page.

```
string[] words2 = null;                
string CurrentPage = " ";

for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
{
    CurrentPage = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page);
    //here split the all data of the page in the form of line and store in the string array
    words2 = CurrentPage.Split('\n');
    words2.ToList();

}
```

How can I add the 10,000 lines of text to the same list?

Comment: After calling `words2.ToList()` you need to assign it to something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<string> words2 = new List<string>();                
string CurrentPage = null;
        for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            CurrentPage = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page);
           //here split the all data of the page in the form of line and store in the string array

            words2.AddRange(CurrentPage.Split('\n'));
        }` 
//if you want an array at the end.
string[] words3 = words2.ToArray();
```

Was there anything else that you were expecting?

Comment: if this was the answer that you were looking for, mark it as one, so it can help others